# Case insensitive sorting in slick using sortBy method

Tags: scala, slick

```
<>.sortBy(c => c.Name.asc).take(10)
```

this sort in slick considers 'Z' before 'a',
is there any was to get a case insensitive sorting in slick?

Comment: I think sorting depends on the collation of the column in the database. Slick doesn't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to control case insensitive sorting:

- the first option is good if you can control the database columns and want to force the case insensitive behaviour everywhere
- the second option is good if you need to do this in only a few, controlled, places.

### 1. Column collation

As @bmateusz said, the sorting is controlled by the collation of the column. This can be set when you create or modify a column (or table, or perhaps the database). It is likely to be specific to the database you're using.

Considering H2, a table containing the names "alice" and "Bob" will sort by default (in H2) as: "Bob" first, then "alice".

You can change that when you define the column:

```
case class Message(name: String, id: Long = 0L)

final class MessageTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Message](tag, "message") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name", O.SqlType("VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(255)") )
  def * = (name, id).mapTo[Message]
}
```

Notice I've specified a column type that's specific to H2: `VARCHAR_IGNORECASE`.

Running this code:

```
val testData = List( Message("alice"), Message("Bob") )

val program = for {
  _ <- messages.schema.create
  _ <- messages ++= testData
  results <- q.sortBy(c => c.name.asc).result
} yield results

val db = Database.forConfig("example")
try Await.result(db.run(program), 2.seconds).foreach(println)
finally db.close
```

... will produce the order: "alice", "Bob".

The database you're using should have a page describing your collation options. Examples include:

- PostgreSQL: [Collation Support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html)
- MySQL: [Character Sets and Collations in General](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html)

If you're not using Slick to define your tables, you can, of course, adjust the collation outside of Slick (using whatever tools or commands you use to control the schema).

### 2. Changing the case in your query

A trick to get case insensitive sorting is to change the query to convert text into one case. For example:

```
val q = messages.sortBy(c => c.name.toLowerCase.asc)
```

Switching to lowercase should have a similar effect. The above Slick query will produce SQL along the lines of:

```
select "name", "id" from "message" order by lcase("name"))
```